# Android WorkManager Not Firing on Correct Times

Tags: android, xamarin, android-workmanager

I am trying to execute a background task every 15 minutes. I am logging the doWork method, so i can see whether its firing correctly or not. However its firing on its own schedule. and yesterday it fired only ONCE. is there something i am missing? I am using ***Xamarin*** (c# synax).

under **MainActivity**:

```
    PeriodicWorkRequest AdhanScheduleSvc = PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder.From<AdhanScheduleWorker>(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15)).Build();
    //WorkManager.Instance.Enqueue(AdhanScheduleSvc);
    WorkManager.GetInstance(Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.AppContext).Enqueue(AdhanScheduleSvc);
```

And my **DoWork**

```
public override Result DoWork()
{
    Android.Util.Log.Debug("AdhanWorker", "Worker Started");

    Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        await CreateSchedules();

    }).ContinueWith(t =>
    {
        if (t.IsFaulted)
        {  // Catch Error
            Android.Util.Log.Debug("AdhanWorker", $"I Completed With Error {t.Exception}");
        };
        if (t.IsCompleted)
        {  //optionally do some work);
            Android.Util.Log.Debug("AdhanWorker", "Worker Completed Success");
        }
    });
```

Comment: I've never used this, but was the device in use by a user, or sitting inactive? Plenty of battery? Plugged in? PeriodicWorkRequest doc says *"Creates a PeriodicWorkRequest to run periodically once every interval period. The PeriodicWorkRequest is guaranteed to run exactly one time during this interval **(subject to OS battery optimizations, such as doze mode)**"* Worst case is a device sitting there, no user interaction, not plugged in => OS puts into "doze mode".

Comment: Yesterday device was in use all day long. it is definitely not the idle issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a sample to test your code and the `DoWork` method will be invoked every 15 minutes in my project.

Here is my class extended the Work:

```
 public class MyWorker : Worker
{
    public MyWorker(Context context, WorkerParameters workerParameters) : base(context, workerParameters) { }
    public override Result DoWork()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("======================================");
        return Result.InvokeSuccess();
    }
}
```

And the code in the MainActivity:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
        var test = PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder.From<MyWorker>(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15)).Build();
        WorkManager.GetInstance(this.ApplicationContext).Enqueue(test);
    }
```

In addition, the worker will use the multi threads to deal with the periodic task, so you don't need to use the Task.Run and async in the `DoWork` method.

Furthermore, I tested it on the Android 12 simulator, you can try to run your project in the difference devices, because the different mobile phone's manufacturers will have different Optimization Policies of the battery.